# why objects cannot convert to a string

Tags: javascript, php, language-agnostic

In programming languages i noticed objects cannot convert to string. Why they implement in such a way.

**php**

```
class abc {
    public $Name;
    public $Number;
    function MrFunction() { /* bla bla bla */ }
}

$foo = new abc();

print_r($foo); //output - abc Object ( [Name] => [Number] => )
echo '<br>';
echo($foo); //output - Catchable fatal error: Object of class abc could not be converted to string on line 11
```

**js**

```
var obj={a:1,b:2};
obj.toString() // output "[object Object]"
```

**P.S** - I don't want to way to convert these object to string i only wanna know why object cant convert to strings

Comment: Why do you want to convert it? you cant `echo` an object.

Comment: what is the reason cannot echo the objects

Comment: echo is for printing strings. you have to convert it first.

Comment: php can echo variables,arrays,.... those are not strings.  then why cant echo object

Comment: `echo` arrays? how do you `echo` arrays in php??

Comment: i check  cant echo arrays but in js arrays can convert to strings.
if can echo variable why cant echo  array,object

Comment: It is `PHP`. And you are doing this `obj.toString()`, which converts it to string.

Comment: no i mentioned it as a additional fact...

now i wanna know  if can echo variable why cant echo array,object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you directly print one object like in your first example, what you are actually printing is the `toString()` method of the object.

In PHP you can manually override the `__toString()` method in the class in the following wat:

```
class abc {
    public $Name;
    public $Number;
    function MrFunction() { /* bla bla bla */ }

    function __toString() {
        return $this->Name.' - '.$this->Number;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able of executing `echo new abc()`.

PS: by convention, classes start with uppercase and variables with lowercase. Therefore it would be `Abc`, `name` and `number` instead of `abc`, `Name` and `Number`.

Comment: what is the reason objects cannot convert to strings and other data types can...as example varible,array,....can convert to string

Comment: They can be converted, but you have to manually specify the way they are going to do it, overriding or defining the toString method.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript. 
You need use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var obj={a:1,b:2};
JSON.stringify(obj); // output "{"a":1,"b":2}"
```

In PHP. You need use `serialize`

```
echo serialize($foo);
```